# Shell script syntax error

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am just starting to learn UNIX and i could not figure the problem here can you please point out the error

```
age=30

if [[ $age -lt  18 ]]

then
        echo "not eligible"

elif  [[ $age -gt 18 && $age -lt 60 ]]
        echo "eligible"
else
        echo "stay home"
fi
exit
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: note: you don't need the `$age -gt 18` ... the first `if` statement takes care of that

Comment: @jsotola Actually, leaving out `$age -gt 18 &&` would make a difference if `age` is 18, but probably your suggestion is the correct one instead of telling the 18 year olds to stay at home with the over-60ies …

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of issues with your script, but the most pressing one is the lack of `then` after the second test.

You also have an unnecessary test for `$age -gt 18`, which additionally introduces a logical error.  You already know that `$age` is less than 18 at that point, and you accidentally leave out the case of `$age` being precisely 18.  It would be better to remove the `$age -gt 18` test altogether.

The script will not need the explicit call to `exit` at the end but should have a `#!`-line at the top pointing to the appropriate shell interpreter (probably `bash`).

You may find https://www.shellcheck.net/ a helpful site for finding the most basic errors in scripts.

---

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

age=30

if [[ $age -lt 18 ]]; then
        echo 'not eligible'
elif [[ $age -lt 60 ]]; then
        echo 'eligible'
else
        echo 'stay home'
fi
```